# Dynamicaly update Google maps with AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, google-maps

I have a lot of addresses in my database I want to add to Google maps as markers. I only want to load and add the markers that are in the selected area on the map. If the map is zoomed or dragged, it should update the markers on the map.
How do I do that?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: The markers are updated by google map automatically on zoom, drag, if you like to change that capture this events.

Answer (score 0):

As Aristos said the markers will be showed automatically when coming into focus. BUT, if I you a bazillion of contacts, it could indeed be easier to do it only when required.

My strategy would be:

- Keep track of the addresses you have added -- no point doing it twice.
- From the address, get the LatLng.
- get the map's current bounds (use getBounds() to get the min/max LatLng of the map currently displayed)
- check whether the LatLng of the address is within the bounds.
- if it is, add a marker.

Loop

If you really have a lot of addresses you might want to prefetch the LatLng and store that in an SQL table. You could then query the table with the intervals.

HTH

**EDIT:** some code. Assuming you have an Array() of markers, and the Northwest and Southeast boundaries, you could do this:

```
function filterMarkers(nw, se, myMarkers) {
  var north=nw.lat();
  var west=nw.lng();
  var south=se.lat();
  var east=se.lng();
  var isInsideBounds=[];
  for (var i in myMarkers) {
    if(myMarkers[i].position.lat()>=north && myMarkers[i].position.lat()=<south && myMarkers[i].position.lng()>=west && myMarkers[i].position.lng()=<east) {
      isInsideBounds.push(myMarkers[i]);
    }
  }
  return isInsideBounds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply!
Do you know of any code examples, that shows how to load only the necessary markes for the selected area on the map?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply!
My plan was to get the markers from a webservice, and let the webservice filter the markes. So i need to tell the webservice som info about the visible area on the maps. As far as i can se, the parameters for the websevice is nw.lat(), nw.lng(), se.lat() and se.lng(). But where do you det nw and se from in your example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For managing a lot of markers, you will definitely want to leverage infrastructure that has already been built to do this.  There is actually a great post on the Google Developers blog that discusses the popular options.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

The Marker Clusterer is a very common component that I see all over the place when it comes to maps apps, and seems to fit the requirements that you are looking for. I would also take a look at Fusion Tables, as it makes building a map with thousands of locations extremely simple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I am already using that function :-) But I am writing all coordinates for the markers in the source code, it fills 200 kbyte. I think it will be more sleek, only to load the markes that is in the shown area of the map.

Comment: Check out the heading titled "Viewport Marker Management" it talks about how to use Ajax to only return the markers in the current viewable area.  Obviously, you will need to limit the zoom level in your app if you go with this approach.